# Execution of a python script and save the output as a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, ssh, paramiko

I would like to save the output of a python script (sshClient.py) as a CSV file. Can you please assist me how to do that? Thanks in advance. The code and resultant output I'm sharing here for your better understanding.

```
import sys
import time
import select
import paramiko

host = '169.254.115.1'
i = 1

#
# Try to connect to the host.
# Retry a few times if it fails.
#
while True:
    print ('Trying to connect to %s (%i/3)' % (host, i))

    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host, port=22, username='user', password='user')
        print ("Connected to %s" % host)
        break
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print ("Authentication failed when connecting to %s") % host
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        print ("Could not SSH to %s, waiting for it to start" % host)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)

    # If we could not connect within time limit
    if i == 3:
        print ("Could not connect to %s. Giving up") % host
        sys.exit(1)

# Send the command (non-blocking)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /opt/cohda/test; sudo ./runtest_iperf_tx.sh")

# Wait for the command to terminate
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
    if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
        if len(rl) > 0:
            # Print data from stdout
            print (stdout.channel.recv(1024)),
#
# Disconnect from the host
#
print ("Command done, closing SSH connection")
ssh.close()
```

The resultant output: [Throughput Vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJEAa.png)

Comment: you could write `(stdout.channel.recv(1024))` to a file (opened in binary mode )instead of printing it.

Comment: Can you pls edit my code to show an example?

Comment: can you post a few lines of the output you're getting as text not image like you did.

Comment: I'm really sorry..Can't provide you that right now as I don't have the device with me right now..

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but something to this effect should work if data is ascii...

```
# Wait for the command to terminate
csv_str = ""
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
    if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
        if len(rl) > 0:
            # Print data from stdout
            print (stdout.channel.recv(1024)),
            csv_str += str.split(str(stdout.channel.recv(1024)),",")
#
# Disconnect from the host
#
PathFileName = "/hard/path/filename.csv"
f = open(PathFileName,'a')
f.write(csv_str)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Need to define 'addrStr' as it says unresolved reference. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Just a silly question. If I'm not wrong then you use the command PathFileName = "/hard/path/filename.csv" for saving the file in a specific location..right?

Comment: Yes, it's just a variable to represent the string for path and file, could be inserted directly in the open() function just as well.